# Error when sink DataStream to JDBC in PyFlink after using map function

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-flink, pyflink

**My Code:**

```
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.jdbc import JdbcSink, JdbcExecutionOptions, JdbcConnectionOptions
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment

JDBC_JAR_PATH = "file:///Users/jar_files/postgresql-42.5.0.jar"

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

env.add_jars(JDBC_JAR_PATH)
env.set_parallelism(1)

type_info = Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.INT()])
ds = env.from_collection(
    [(101, "Stream Processing with Apache Flink", "Fabian Hueske, Vasiliki Kalavri", 2019),
     (102, "Streaming Systems", "Tyler Akidau, Slava Chernyak, Reuven Lax", 2018),
     (103, "Designing Data-Intensive Applications", "Martin Kleppmann", 2017),
     (104, "Kafka: The Definitive Guide", "Gwen Shapira, Neha Narkhede, Todd Palino", 2017)
     ], type_info=type_info).name('Source')


def change_id(data):
    data[0] = data[0] + 100
    return data


ds1 = ds.map(change_id)

ds2 = ds1.add_sink(
    JdbcSink.sink(
        "insert into books(id, title, authors, year) values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
        type_info,
        JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
            .with_url('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nhan_su')
            .with_driver_name('org.postgresql.Driver')
            .with_user_name('psql')
            .with_password('psql')
            .build(),
        JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
            .with_batch_interval_ms(1000)
            .with_batch_size(200)
            .with_max_retries(5)
            .build()
    ))
env.execute()
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class org.apache.flink.types.Row ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.flink.types.Row is in unnamed module of loader 'app') at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.executor.SimpleBatchStatementExecutor.executeBatch(SimpleBatchStatementExecutor.java:70)

How to Sink DataStream to JDBC Sink after Using map function in PyFlink?

I tried to change the return type of map function to tuple, but the issue is still there.

Comment: I using PyFlink 1.16, Python 3.8

Comment: What is your Java runtime version?